# Изменение массива с данными через кликабельный массив

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, reactjs, typescript

Есть массив с данными

```
const array = [
  { questions: [
      {text: "Трехфазный"},
      {text: "Управляемый"}
    ]
  }
]
```

и массив с кнопками (кликабельными изображениями)

```
const buttons = [
  <img className='button1' src='1.svg'></img>,
  <img className='button2' src='2.svg'></img>
]
```

Как при нажатии на первый элемент массива `buttons` менять свойства первого поля `text` ("Трехфазный"), например, сделать это поле красным, а при нажатии на второй элемент массива `buttons` менять аналогичные свойства второго поля text ("Управляемый")?

В общем случае, как менять при нажатии на `i`-ый элемент массива buttons `i`-ое поле `text`?

Хочу что-то вроде

```
<div onClick={() => {

  }
 }
>
  {buttons}
</div>
```

или через `Array.prototype.map()`. Если знаете другие способы, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleButtonClick = (index) => {
  const textElement = document.querySelectorAll('.questions')[index].querySelector('.text');
  textElement.classList.add('red-text');
}

const array = [
  {
    questions: [
      {text: "Трехфазный", class: ""},
      {text: "Управляемый", class: ""}
    ]
  }
]

const buttons = [
  <img className='button1' src='1.svg' onClick={() => handleButtonClick(0)}></img>,
  <img className='button2' src='2.svg' onClick={() => handleButtonClick(1)}></img>
]
```